# Character Position in a Text

Tags: java, dialog

I need help with the following code. I want to the code to print a dialog box that outputs the first position and the last position of the character in the text. The code runs but only outputs "Not Found".

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class CharacterCounter {
    public static Object findFirstAndLast(String text, String textch)
    {
        int n = text.length();
        int first = -1, last = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!textch.equals(text))
                continue;
            if (first == -1)
                first = i;
            last = i;
        }
        if (first != -1) {
            System.out.println("First Occurrence = " + first);
            System.out.println("Last Occurrence = " + last);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text;
        String textch;
        int amountOFC = 0;

        text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter text");
        text = text.toLowerCase();

        textch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter character");
        textch = textch.toLowerCase();

        for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++){
            if(text.charAt(i) == textch) {
                amountOFC++;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sentense contains " + text.length()+
                " and "+ amountOFC + " var " + textch);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "positions" + findFirstAndLast(text,textch));
    }
}
```

Also the code line `text.charAt(i) == textch`seems to generate a error that "==" can not be applied to char. Please tell me how do I address these issues.
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What's the error

Comment: `text.charAt(i) == textch` produces an error because `textch` is a String and `charAt()` returns a `char`. Those are different types, and you can't compare them with `==` like you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the alternative in this case @JustAnotherDeveloper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also the code line `text.charAt(i) == textch` seems to generate a error
> that "==" can not be applied to char.

It's because you are trying to compare a `char` value with  `String` value (stored in `textch`).

Moreover, you can use [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) functions to find the first and the last positions respectively.

**Demo:**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter text").toLowerCase();
        String textch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter character").toLowerCase();
        int amountOFC = 0;
        if (textch.length() >= 1) {
            char ch = textch.charAt(0);// First character
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if (text.charAt(i) == ch) {
                    amountOFC++;
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Texten hade " + text.length() + " tecken varav " + amountOFC + " var " + textch);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "First position is " + text.indexOf(ch) + ", Last position is " + text.lastIndexOf(ch));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use standard methods `String#contains`, `String#indexOf`, `String#lastIndexOf`?

If so:

```java
String text = ...;
String substring = ...;
if(text.contains(substring)) {
    System.out.println("First Occurrence = " + text.indexOf(substring));
    System.out.println("Last Occurrence = " + text.lastIndexOf(substring));
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```